# postgresql: INSERT INTO statement with select query

Tags: postgresql, select, insert, subquery

I have to insert some data in my `table` of existing `client_id` column , so i am using select with insert

`INSERT into 'my_table' (column1, client_id, column3) VALUES (val1,select distinct client_id from 'my_table', val3)`

I need client_id from the same table `my_table` and i need client_ids in insert statement.

`SELECT DISTINCT client_id FROM my_table`  gives me 113 client_id so i want to insert some row for each 113 client using the above approach.

I did this query

`INSERT INTO client_notification_preferences (client_id, object_type , frequency,created_at,updated_at) SELECT DISTINCT client_id, 'ClientShipment',1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP FROM client_notification_preferences;`

but this gives me this error
[image]

```
 create_table "client_notification_preferences", id: :uuid, default: "uuid_generate_v4()", force: :cascade do |t|
t.uuid     "client_id"
t.string   "object_type"
t.integer  "frequency"
t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
```

end

Comment: Show us the table definition for `client_notification_preferences`.

Comment: when I insert any row, id is automatically inserted so how can it violate primary key constraint

Comment: Well, you have some unique constraint which is being violated.

Answer (score 6):

if val1 and val3 are variables and client_id is a field from my_table you can use from below code.

```
 INSERT into 'my_table' (column1, client_id, column3) select distinct val1, 
    client_id,val3 from 'my_table'
```

for example

```
INSERT into 'my_table' (column1, client_id, column3) select distinct 1, client_id,2 from 'my_table'
```

Comment: i only need client_id from select statement, and select distinct client_id from 'my_table' will give me 113 client_ids together , but i need one client at a time for inserting data

Comment: do you need last client_Id?

Comment: i need all client_id

Comment: What is `val1` ?

Comment: 'val1' is a value